# How can I create SignIn and SignOut with 1 button in RxSwift?

Tags: mvvm, rx-swift

[image]

[image]

Here my code to change text in button:

```
func transform(input: Input) -> Output {
        
        let tappedSigninCheck = input.signinTrigger
            .scan(false) { lastState, _ in
                return !lastState }
        
        let singupButtonTitle = tappedSigninCheck.map {
            return $0 == true ? "Sign Out" : "Sign In"
        }
                
        return Output(signinButtonTitle: singupButtonTitle)
    }
```

Now when I clicked SignIn, button text will change to "Sign Out" and I want when click Sign Out, sign out will display 1 alert and when click Yes in alert then button text change to Sign In.
My problem: whenever I click in button then button text change text :(((

```
func bindViewModel() {
        let signoutTrigger = signinButton.rx.tap.flatMap {
            return Observable<Void>.create { (observer) -> Disposable in
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Are you sure to sign out?",
                                              message: nil,
                                              preferredStyle: .alert)
                
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No",
                                              style: .cancel,
                                              handler: nil))
                
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes",
                                              style: .destructive,
                                              handler: { _ in
                                                    observer.onNext(Void())
                }))
                self.present(alert, animated: true)
                return Disposables.create()
            }
        }
        
        let input = ProfileViewModel.Input(signinTrigger: signinButton.rx.tap.asDriver(),
                                           signoutTrigger: signoutTrigger.asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: Void()))
        
        let output = profileViewModel.transform(input: input)
        
        output
            .signinButtonTitle
            .drive(signinButton.rx.title)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
                
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you will need a feedback loop, and that calls for a `Subject`. I suggest you do it something like below. Also note that you forgot to emit a `completed` event on your alert.:

```
class ViewModel {

    struct Input {
        let logButton: Observable<Void>
        let okayButton: Observable<Void>
    }

    struct Output {
        let buttonTitle: Observable<String>
        let displayAlert: Observable<Void>
    }

    private enum Action {
        case tapped
        case okay
    }

    private enum State {
        case offline
        case online
        case check
    }

    func transform(_ input: Input) -> Output {
        let state = Observable.merge(
            input.logButton.map(to: ViewModel.Action.tapped),
            input.okayButton.map(to: ViewModel.Action.okay)
        )
            .scan(ViewModel.State.offline) { state, action in
                switch (state, action) {
                case (.offline, .tapped):
                    return .online
                case (.online, .tapped):
                    return .check
                case (.check, .okay):
                    return .offline
                case (.check, .tapped):
                    return .check
                default:
                    assert(false)
                    return state
                }
            }
            .share()

        let buttonTitle = state
            .map { $0 == .offline ? "Log In" : "Log Out" }

        let displayAlert = state
            .filter { $0 == .check }
            .map(to: ())

        return Output(
            buttonTitle: buttonTitle,
            displayAlert: displayAlert
        )
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var button: UIButton!
    var viewModoel: ViewModel!
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    func bind() {
        let logout = PublishSubject<Void>()
        let input = ViewModel.Input(
            logButton: button.rx.tap.asObservable(),
            okayButton: logout
        )
        let output = viewModoel.transform(input)

        output.buttonTitle
            .bind(to: button.rx.title(for: .normal))
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)


        output.displayAlert
            .flatMap { [unowned self] _ in
                self.areYouSure()
            }
            .bind(to: logout)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

    func areYouSure() -> Observable<Void> {
        Observable.create { [unowned self] observer in
            let alert = UIAlertController(
                title: "Are you sure to sign out?",
                message: nil,
                preferredStyle: .alert
            )
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(
                title: "Yes", style: .destructive, handler: { _ in
                    observer.onNext(())
                    observer.onCompleted()
                }
            ))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(
                title: "No", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                    observer.onCompleted()
                }
            ))

            self.present(alert, animated: true)
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I also tried with enum but I wrote wrong. I really looked forward to your reply. Thank you again ^^

Comment: The `scan` operator represents a [Moore style state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_machine). If you use a [Mealy machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mealy_machine) you can do it with just two states, but for a Moore machine, you need three.